# Spring Interceptor Handler Interceptor afterCompletion need to configure for jersey res API url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jersey

we are using jersey with spring application in that for a specific require i need to implement Interceptor for a url that afterComplete the response send to client i found in Spring  Handler Interceptor afterCompletion method that suits for me, but when i implement that it not calling from jersey rest api, how should i configure that in jersey rest url

Comment: show us some code / config so that we could base our advice on something

Comment: Use a [ContainerResponseFilter or WriterInterceptor](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)